# How do i connect to aws elastic search via javascript client in react js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have a react js with typescript project and code below. here are the steps i followed. I ran following commands to install and then ran the code. it always times out. the keys that i'm using belong to the aws user who has full access to the ES domain. also, i have found it being used , this is someone else's code ,  as such (right below)

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var connectionClass = require('http-aws-es');
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client({  
    host: ***,
    log: 'error',
    connectionClass: connectionClass,
    **amazonES:** {
      credentials: new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS')
    }
});
```

it defines amazonES (in bold above). when i try to use as above , amazonES is not even defined for the elasticsearch client , is that in the previous version. ??? Below is mycode.

1. npm install elasticsearch7.x ( this downloaded the latest version elasticsearch.js 16.7.1 ->  https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch)
2. npm install http-aws-es
3. npm install aws-sdk

code is

```
import es from 'elasticsearch'; 
import connectionClass from 'http-aws-es';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'; 

let client = elasticsearch.Client({
    hosts: ['host'],
    connectionClass: require('http-aws-es'),
    awsConfig: new AWS.Config({
        accessKeyId: 'AKID', secretAccessKey: 'SECRET', region: 'us-west-2'
    })
});

client.ping({
  requestTimeout: 5000
}, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('success');
  }
});
```

Comment: usually I dont use aws credential from the browser based applications. because anyone can see the source of your website and find your credentials there. are you following any articles. can i have a look ?

Comment: @ArunK - this is not running on browser though. it is a backend node app on the server.

Comment: In that case, why do you have to configure access credentials. you can use IAM roles. or are you testing this on your local machine?